# Make bubbles and balloons with sprite kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, gravity

How would I create things like balloons and bubbles in a Sprite Kit physics world?

Their physics bodies' should be affected by gravity, right?
But is there no way to set individual gravity per sprite?

Update:
According to a forum post this is how Box2d does the local gravity:
Maybe it can be replicated for games using other physics engines.

```
b.m_linearVelocity.x += step.dt * (gravity.x + b.m_invMass * b.m_force.x);
b.m_linearVelocity.y += step.dt * (gravity.y + b.m_invMass * b.m_force.y);
```

From http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=27576&sid=24a8448ae05c9e3c97a3f8c02aa5a175#p27576

Comment: Box2d has the individual gravity for individual sprites. I wonder if I  should just try to use Box2d with sprite kit and not use SKPhysicsBody and the other physics code of Sprite Kit at all.

Comment: I also noticed that there is no such thing in Chipmunk (cocos2d 3) either... :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to set individual gravity per sprite, but you can apply force to the bubble:

```
- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {
    [bubbleNode.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(0,300)];
}
```

Comment: I am using this right now, but it's important to set affectedByGravity to NO as well. And play around with different (low) densities and change that force vector around to get a good feeling. Bubbles and balloons should feel "light".